# Angular 4 - Socket.io update view on emitted event

Tags: angular, socket.io, observable

I have the following code to my component

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.siteService.socket.on("users_online_now", function(usersOnlineNow){
        this.usersOnlineNow = usersOnlineNow;
        console.log(usersOnlineNow);
    });

}
```

Even the console.log prints the number to the console, the view doesn't change to my template. Is there any other more simple way than BehaviourSubject?

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrow function (`=>`) instead of `function`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.siteService.socket.on("users_online_now", (usersOnlineNow) => {
        this.usersOnlineNow = usersOnlineNow;
        console.log(usersOnlineNow);
    });
}
```

Otherwise `this` is not pointing to your class instance.

Comment: Finally... This was only 1 part of the answer. I had to inject "private ref: ChangeDetectorRef" and call "this.ref.markForCheck();" after my change.